# Being too stupid to implement Appium Java client into Android Studio Project

Tags: android, appium, java-client

I recently started coding my really first android project using Android Studio 3.1.2 and SDK 19 (Android 4.4).

When I came across testing I want to automate my UI-tests, which I plan to write with the java client of Appium (the server will be set up externally). In order to get the java-Client including all the drivers I added a dependency into the `build.gradle(app)`:

```
implementation 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0'
```

Synching Gradle after adding the dependency didn't cause any recognizable problems. Now if I try to run one of my (non-UI) tests, I get a `DexArchiveBuilderException` already during the build process, throwing a wall of text, that somehow hints, that several resources of `io.appium:java-client:6.1.0` require APIs from newer Android SDKs:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.Object org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService$ThrowingSupplier.get()","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): org.springframework.core.env.Environment org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment()","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler.schedule(java.lang.Runnable, java.time.Instant)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): boolean org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor.requiresDestruction(java.lang.Object)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): boolean org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean.isSingleton()","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): boolean org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartFactoryBean.isEagerInit()","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

Beneath the actual exception:

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/ini/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.12.0/b44da882625fdc1e8e99035b3d1bb488d17802e6/selenium-firefox-driver-3.12.0.jar
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:308)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I hardly have any experience in test automation, so the official Appium documentation doesn't really explain to me, if it's possible to make the client run on SDK 19 and if this is the case, how to do that. Does anyone of you guys know how to do this? Or am I just foolhardy and forgot a required step during the integration? Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automate with Appium Java client, it's best to keep it's test project separate from the Android project and use your built app APK in the Appium test.

If you want to keep your test together with the Android project, it's best to use Espresso as it's a part of the Android SDK.

Comment: I also thought about switching to espresso, though Appium (or Selenium, which is already in use in our deployment) provide an espresso driver