# My Android Studio upgraded to 3.2.1 and when i build i am getting errors

Tags: android-studio, appium-android

I am automating mobile apps using Appium on Android studio and recently my android studio upgraded to 3.2.1 now I can not build my project. I am getting the below error, I have tried all sort of searching the error with no luck. Please help .Thank you

**Error below**

Error: Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: Someone already tried using Appium in Android studio project and he also got the same issue as you, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002115/5320558