# How to write test cases for an android app in the android studio and results in Appium server?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have developed an android app in the android studio and I need to test it. I have selected the Appium as my testing tool to test the app. I need to know how to test the android app using Appium by writing test cases in the android studio (in macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6). Can anyone provide me the detail process of doing this work?

Platform: Android studio 3.2.2,
Testing tool: Appium v1.9.2,
Operating system: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

I need to know how to write test cases in the android studio for testing an android app using Appium only.

I have gone through many documents but I can't understand how to make it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already some questions related to the case you want. But all of them faced problems implementing Appium tests with Android project.

It's best to keep Android project and your Appium test project separate.

Check my answer / comment for similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988337/my-android-studio-upgraded-to-3-2-1-and-when-i-build-i-am-getting-errors#comment92918509_52988337).